# How to get rid of VSMacros80 folder from project root?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I have it so Visual Studio doesn't keep re-creating this folder that I never use. It's annoying ot keep looking and unnecessary.

Comment: I know this is a major thread necro :-) The accepted answer is incorrect, btw

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
Tools->Options->Addin/Macro Security
```

Change Paths there.

Comment: The path isn't one of the ones listed, so you can't change it there.

Answer (score 3):

Add a trailing slash to the default projects location:

[Get Rid of the Annoying VSMacros80 Folder](http://rerrify.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/get-rid-of-the-annoying-vsmacros80-folder-5/)

Comment: Honestly, I did not believe you until I tried it! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "/" on the end of your "Projects location". (Tested on 2010 SP1.)

[Remove VSMacros80 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377/remove-vsmacros80-directory)