# Remove VSMacros80 directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Is there any way to prevent Visual Studio from creating a VSMacros80 folder in my default project directory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found it out myself: If you add a trailing backslash to the *Project Folder* setting e.g. changing it from `C:\dev` to `C:\dev\`, the `VSMacros80` directory will no longer be created.

I tested it with Visual Studio 2005 SP1, with all windows updates installed.

Comment: Works even in Visual Studio 2010... *Amazing find!*

Comment: Let's hope they don't patch it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I was wrong. This directory will allways be created. You can only set it's path in the Options/Projects and Solutions/General screen in the Projects location.

But be careful, because it also means that your standard project directory will be this directory. You cannot avoid VS to create this directory.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the file as 'hidden.' Visual Studio won't mess with the visibility setting (or, at least, it didn't when I did it in 2010).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the previous thread, because I was searching for "vsmacros" instead of "vsmacros80".

There are currently 5 different entries in `Tools->Options->Addin/Macro Security`

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\MsEnvShared\Addins
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\MsEnvShared\Addins
%VSAPPDATA%\Addins
%VSCOMMONAPPDATA%\Addins
%VSMYDOCUMENTS%\Addins
```

Can you tell me which one I have to delete?